# AWS SAM - How to combine stage variables with Fn::Sub on swagger endpoint uri

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sam

We have a stack that makes use of the other stack's output with cross-stack referencing using `Fn::ImportValue` within a swagger definition body.

> Note: other parts ommitted to shorten the code

```
SampleApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    StageName: Stage
    Variables:
      SampleFunctionName:
        Fn::ImportValue: 
          !Sub ${OtherStackName}-SampleFunctionName
    DefinitionBody:
      swagger: 2.0
      paths:
        /sample:
          get:
            x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
              uri:
                Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${stageVariables.SampleFunctionName}/invocations
```

Where `${OtherStackName}-SampleFunctionName` is the name of the function that's being imported from other stack.

Now, our problem now is that we cannot put it inside the endpoint's `uri`. Cloudformation is complaining about it during sam deploy, saying that `${stageVariables.SampleFunctionName}` is an illegal attribute inside Fn::Sub.

I have tried several ways including putting the whole `uri` on the stage variable itself, but still it does not come.

Your thoughts are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it to work this way

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  uri:
    Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/
        - Fn::ImportValue: 
            Fn::Sub: ${StackName}-FunctionArn
        - /invocations
```

For some reason, shorthand functions won't work inside `uri` and `${stageVariables.<somename>}` do not work inside an Fn::Sub function.

> Note that this only happens inside a swagger definition body

Answer (score 3):

Fn::Sub was supported from the version v0.21.0 of SAM CLI. The versions below 0.21.0 does not support most of the Cloudformation Intrinsic Functions.

Can check the below link for more details:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/528

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v0.21.0

If your using the version below the mentioned one you can try using Fn::Join instead of Fn::Sub as a workround

```
                uri: !Join
                      - ''
                      - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
                        - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                        - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:'
                        - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                        - ':'
                        - !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
                        - ':function:${stageVariables.SampleFunctionName}/invocations'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to give your answer. Its kind of bulky but it works anyways. I ended up modifying your script and made our deployment work.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff had mentioned Stage Variables does not work inside an Fn::Sub function. However, if anyone wishes to use Stage Variables inside uri string, the below code worked for me.

```
uri:
  Fn::Join:
    - ''
    - - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/
      - Fn::Sub: ${LambaFunctionResource.Arn}
      - :${stageVariables.<stageVariableName>}
      - /invocations
```